# Multiple Monitors, only one hdmi port (laptop)

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I just bought a new laptop (lenovo Y50 to be exact) and with my old laptop I had two additional screens hooked up to it but with this new laptop, it only has one hdmi output cable but it has a NVIDIA gtx 860m which I know can support multiple monitors because I had the same card in my old laptop, I want to connect the two extra monitors into my new laptop but the one hdmi port is being quite the nuisance, Is it best to just buy a splitter and extend the resolution so it extends to both screens or is there a way to port both screens into the one hdmi port (or perhapse i could use a USB but i'd prefer not to). Also I could convert the hdmi to dvi and split that if it would be better, but i'm not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: Splitting a video port sends the same signal to both monitors.  If you want different content on the two monitors, you will need a second video port of some kind.

Comment: @fixer1234 Well yeah but it's a laptop and it only has the one video port, so what should I do?

Comment: USB?  WiFi device?  Ethernet device?  Something like Google TV?  I don't know if any of the cable or satellite services offer a feature where you stream to your router or other interface and can than view it on your TV cable.  The problem with a laptop is that there are limitations to what features you can add.  Without re-engineering it, you are pretty much stuck with a solution that uses the existing connections.

Comment: @fixer1234 Maybe USB would be the best way to go, I doubt it but I believe I saw somewhere that the Ethernet port could be used but I have doubts, can it be used? or should I just go with USB?

Comment: Most monitors don't have Ethernet ports.  Using Ethernet would likely require using some other device to feed your monitor.  Ethernet would just provide a network connection to that device.  I've never used USB to directly connect a video signal so I don't know whether you need an additional device for this, also.  You might need to do some Google research or perhaps someone more familiar with the options can offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo offers a USB 3 Docking Station, having an additional set of ports. Two of them are DVI ports.